# in the tkinter module, How would I make the gui wait until input has been registered

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this as my code, and roughly halfway through is a while loop waiting until the variable self.sub is 1. this is giving me issues, as it will no longer run. it will say its running, but its not. I would be more specific, but I don't know how.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text_width = 100


def destroy_root():
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        a = 0

class Application(Frame):
    sub = 0

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def submit(self):
        if len(self.entry.get()) != 0:
            self.text.config(width=text_width, state=NORMAL)
            self.text.insert(END, '\n'+(str(self.entry.get())))
            self.entry.delete(0, END)
            self.text.config(width=text_width, state=DISABLED)
            self.text.see(END)
            self.sub = 1

    def story(self):
        self.text.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.text.insert(END, '\nWelcome to the interactive, text-based game of Dimensia!\n\n_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_\n\n'
                              'Where reality is not what it seems, and parallels are more familiar than ever\n\n')
        self.text.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.sub = 0

        condition = True
        while condition:
            if self.sub == 1:
                condition = False

        self.text.config(state=NORMAL)
        self.text.insert(END, 'Hello')
        self.text.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.sub = 0



    def createWidgets(self):
        self.text = Text(self)
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)
        self.text.config(width=text_width, height=45, state=DISABLED)

        self.border = Label(self)
        self.border.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2)
        self.border.config(height=43, background='black')

        instruction = 'Welcome to your personal scratchpad!!\n\n'
        self.scratch_pad = Text(self)
        self.scratch_pad.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=2, rowspan=2)
        self.scratch_pad.config(width=50, height=30)
        self.scratch_pad.insert(END, 'Scratch Pad\n_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_\n\n\n\n'+str(instruction))

        self.QUIT = Button(self, command=self.quit)
        self.QUIT.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.QUIT.config(width=1, text='Q')

        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3)
        self.entry.config(width=120)

        self.submit_b = Button(self, text='Submit')
        self.submit_b.config(command=self.submit)
        self.submit_b.grid(row=2, column=4)

        frame = Frame(self)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)
        frame.config(height=1)

        health_label = Label(frame, text='Health')
        health_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        stamina_label = Label(frame, text='Stamina')
        stamina_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        mana_label = Label(frame, text='Mana')
        mana_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
        courage_label = Label(frame, text='Courage')
        courage_label.grid(row=6, column=0)


        energy_label = Label(frame, text='Energy')
        energy_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
        strength_label = Label(frame, text='Strength')
        strength_label.grid(row=2, column=1)
        knowledge_label = Label(frame, text='Knowledge')
        knowledge_label.grid(row=4, column=1)
        confusion_label = Label(frame, text='Confusion')
        confusion_label.grid(row=6, column=1)


        inteligence_label = Label(frame, text='Inteligence')
        inteligence_label.grid(row=0, column=2)
        agility_label = Label(frame, text='Agility')
        agility_label.grid(row=2, column=2)
        hunger_label = Label(frame, text='Hunger')
        hunger_label.grid(row=4, column=2)
        coins_label = Label(frame, text='Coins')
        coins_label.grid(row=6, column=2)

        curiosity_label = Label(frame, text='Curiosity')
        curiosity_label.grid(row=0, column=3)
        fear_label = Label(frame, text='Fear')
        fear_label.grid(row=2, column=3)



        health_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Health', width=5)
        health_value.grid(row=1, column=0)
        health_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        stamina_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Stamina', width=5)
        stamina_value.grid(row=3, column=0)
        stamina_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        mana_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Mana', width=5)
        mana_value.grid(row=5, column=0)
        mana_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        courage_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Courage', width=5)
        courage_value.grid(row=7, column=0)
        courage_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)


        strength_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Strength', width=5)
        strength_value.grid(row=3, column=1)
        strength_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        knowledge_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Knowledge', width=5)
        knowledge_value.grid(row=5, column=1)
        knowledge_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        confusion_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Confusion', width=5)
        confusion_value.grid(row=7, column=1)
        confusion_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        energy_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Energy', width=5)
        energy_value.grid(row=1, column=1)
        energy_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)


        inteligence_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Inteligence', width=5)
        inteligence_value.grid(row=1, column=2)
        inteligence_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        agility_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Agility', width=5)
        agility_value.grid(row=3, column=2)
        agility_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        hunger_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Hunger', width=5)
        hunger_value.grid(row=5, column=2)
        hunger_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        coins_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Coins', width=5)
        coins_value.grid(row=7, column=2)
        coins_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)


        curiosity_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Curiosity', width=5)
        curiosity_value.grid(row=1, column=3)
        curiosity_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)
        fear_value = Spinbox(frame, text='Fear', width=5)
        fear_value.grid(row=3, column=3)
        fear_value.config(from_=0, to_=100, state=DISABLED)

        health_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        health_value.config(value=100)
        health_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        stamina_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        stamina_value.config(value=100)
        stamina_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        mana_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        mana_value.config(value=0)
        mana_value.config(state=DISABLED)
        mana_label.config(state=DISABLED)

        courage_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        courage_value.config(value=50)
        courage_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        strength_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        strength_value.config(value=35)
        strength_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        knowledge_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        knowledge_value.config(value=5)
        knowledge_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        confusion_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        confusion_value.config(value=75)
        confusion_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        energy_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        energy_value.config(value=100)
        energy_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        inteligence_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        inteligence_value.config(value=50)
        inteligence_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        agility_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        agility_value.config(value=50)
        agility_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        hunger_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        hunger_value.config(value=50)
        hunger_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        coins_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        coins_value.config(value=150)
        coins_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        curiosity_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        curiosity_value.config(value=50)
        curiosity_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        fear_value.config(state=NORMAL)
        fear_value.config(value=25)
        fear_value.config(state=DISABLED)

        self.story()




    a = 0


root.wm_title('Dimensia')
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
destroy_root()
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

GUIs are already in a perpetual state of waiting for conditions -- this is called the event loop. So, you shouldn't ever need to put in your own loop that waits for something. In fact, your code *is* waiting, even before your while loop. It waits until the user presses the submit button, then it calls a function.

You need to remove your while loop, and simply respond to the event appropriately in your button callback, or in a function called by your callback.